# Upgrade Indigo package versions (particularly moveit_commander)

Tags: ros, apt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(Moved from [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/251282/how-to-change-velocity-acceleration-in-motionplanrequest-topic/?answer=256913#post-id-256913) on behalf of @shzargar)

I want to use `set_max_acceleration_scaling_factor` (newly added method to moveit_commander) in my python program to control the velocity but I get:

```
  File "./nextage_moveit_waypoint.py", line 117, in main
    larm.set_max_velocity_scaling_factor(0.5)   
AttributeError: 'MoveGroupCommander' object has no attribute 'set_max_velocity_scaling_factor'
```

running this : `rosversion moveit_commander`
gives me this: 0.6.1

I tried to do update with
`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-full-pr2` (or `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit`)
`source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`

but at the end, `rosversion moveit_commander` returns me the same version.

How I can update my moveit_commander and make sure that I have `set_max_acceleration_scaling_factor`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256922/upgrade-indigo-package-versions-(particularly-moveit_commander)/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2017-03-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`moveit_commander` for ROS Indigo at the time of writing is version 0.7.8 ([changelog](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/e1605fac22350cf7dcadbbde3aeb8e0bfbb5c04f/moveit_commander/CHANGELOG.rst)), but its binary is [not yet available to general public](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_default.html?q=moveit_commander) and only available on so-called ["shadow" repository](http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository) (testing repo before the public release). You can apply the setting in the link and update.

Note that in order to update an already-installed Ubuntu package you may want to run `apt-get` with `--reinstall` option, e.g.:

```
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-indigo-moveit-commander
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1